# Is there a unified Webpack configuration?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

Webpack has a bunch of benefits -- it allows your to bundle your files into separate chunks with different entry points, it allows you to rip out stale or unused code, and it allows you to bundle static assets with javascript. This all sounds amazing, but it is still challenging to shared code.

Suppose I build a package to be webpack-compatible, and it uses require statements for SCSS, images, and Coffeescript. And suppose some other webpack-compatible package imports Stylus and JSX. How am I supposed to use these packages when there is no standard configuration?

In addition to just setting up the loaders, there are a slew of other configurations like where to resolve the root of the package so you can require absolute paths (which is convenient so you can find-all-replace when you move or rename a file).

I think this issue is only more evident by this compile-time warning I get every once in a while:

> This seems to be a pre-built javascript file. Though this is possible, it's not recommended. Try to require the original source to get better results.

I would love to produce packages that work well with webpack complete with UI components, styles, and other static assets, but I'm not sure what the best practices are for doing this.

Is there some community standard for webpack configurations? If not, maybe we should start one...